# How to get crontab job depencies working and avoid command not found

Tags: python, bash, path, cron

My cron job needs to run a shell script which calls python commands which depends on python and a pip package.  How can I get my script to work in cron?

My shell script is simply

```
#!/bin/bash
TOKEN=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
bdate=$(date -d "$date -30 days" +"%Y%m%d")
# slack-cleaner was installed with pip install slack-cleaner
slack-cleaner --token $TOKEN --message --channel ci-builds --botname circle-ci --before $bdate
```

My crontab is

```
50 3 * * *  bash /home/myuser/bin/slack_cleaner.sh
```

I get the errors in the mail log

```
tail -f /var/mail/myuser # outputs 
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/myuser>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=myuser>
Message-Id: <20210108034301.5F00F44531@someplace>
Date: Fri,  8 Jan 2021 03:43:01 +0000 (UTC)

/home/myuser/bin/slack_cleaner.sh: line 5: slack-cleaner: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the user's PATH variable in `crontab -e`

1. copy the output of `echo $PATH` and then run `crontab -e`
2. add these 2 lines before your cron job(s)

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=<paste what you copied in step 2 here>
```